# Post always not executed on declarative pipeline exception

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Ideally, I want to handle a failure in my declarative Jenkins pipeline and send an email to the committee. But I cannot make post to work at all. I have the following script:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Prepare') {
            steps {
                cleanWs
                checkout scm
            }
        } 
    }

    post {
        always {
            echo '============'
            echo 'In Post part'
            echo '============'
            echo currentBuild.result  // this prints null
        }
    }
}
```

In my version of Jenkins `cleanWs()` is not defined, so the build fails with:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 11: Expected a step @ line 11, column 17.
                   cleanWs
                   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1073)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:516)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:479)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:253)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Finished: FAILURE
```

But as you can see, there is no

```
============
In Post part
============
```

So the `post` `always` was not executed.

Answer (score 4):

Your pipeline is not executed at all, see the error: `MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:`. As the pipeline script cannot even be compiled, a job does not start at all, so obviously `post` block isn't executed. Since the source cannot be compiled, jenkins is not aware of any `post` block anyway.